# Click on a control using AutoIt if a window is present in the background or in the front

Tags: automation, autoit

I want to click a button that is present on a form of an EXE file.

Below is my code that I have tried.

```
WinWaitActive("ABCD")
ControlClick("ABCD","Defer","[CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:2]")
Run("ClickDefer.exe")
```

- The first line, `WinWaitActive("ABCD")` waits till a window named **ABCD** comes into focus.
- The second line clicks on a button, **Defer**
- The third line runs the same EXE file for handling same scenario if it occurs.

This works properly if the **ABCD** window comes into focus. It doesn't work if it is not in focus. How do I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you should use an infinite loop instead of running the same compiled script over and over again. And JonBecher is right, but missing the case, where the window never becomes active. So your solution would be:

```
While True
    $win = WinWait("ABCD", "Defer")
    ControlClick($win, "", "[CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:2]")
    WinWaitClose($win)
Wend
```

This implies, that your click will close the window and you want to wait for the same window to appear again somewhen in the future. Else your complete intenional `Run(...)`-call wouldn't make sense.

With `ControlClick(...)` you don't need to have your window active or even visible.

Answer (score 2):

Using `WinActivate` you can make a window come into focus.

`WinActivate("ABCD")`

This will bring the focus to the "ABCD" window.

```
WinWaitActive("ABCD")
WinActivate("ABCD")
ControlClick("ABCD","Defer","[CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:2]")
Run("ClickDefer.exe")
```

Answer (score 0):

if you sending control key, then no need to wait or focus on that window. it will handle...  I am writing this code for Skype sso, no matter where is window... It works if window is minimized.

```
#include <WinAPI.au3>
$pId = Run("C:/Program Files (x86)/Skype/Phone/Skype.exe")

Local $hWnd = WinWait("[CLASS:TLoginForm]", "", 10)

sleep(8000)

ControlSend($hWnd, "", "[CLASS:Internet Explorer_Server]", "Passw0rd")

sleep(1000)

ControlSend($hWnd, "", "[CLASS:Internet Explorer_Server]", "{TAB}")

sleep(1000)

ControlSend($hWnd, "", "[CLASS:Internet Explorer_Server]", "{Enter}")
```